# How to best perform a surface integral over 2D point data?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have a data set of 363 x- by 190 y-points with an associated functional value that I would to integrate over multiple different subregions..  I've tried to create a SciPy `interp2d` function to integrate; however, **creating that function even with linear interpolation has taken over 2 hours (and is not yet done)**.

What is a better approach to perform this task?

Some snippets below...

In the `convert_RT_to_XY` function below, imb/jmb are the r,theta mesh boundaries that I convert to Cartesian boundaries.

Later, in my code, I convert the mesh boundaries (imb/jmb) to mesh-center values (imm,jmm), convert to vectors (iX, iY), convert my function a vector (iZ), and then attempt to make my interpolation function.

---

```
# Convert R, T mesh vectors to X, Y mesh arrays.                                                                       
def convert_RT_to_XY(imb, jmb):                                                                                        
    R, T = np.meshgrid(imb,jmb)                                                                                        
    X = R * np.cos(np.radians(T*360))                                                                                  
    Y = R * np.sin(np.radians(T*360))                                                                                  
    return(X, Y)
```

...

```
imm = imb[:-1]+np.divide(np.diff(imb),2)                                                                       
jmm = jmb[:-1]+np.divide(np.diff(jmb),2) 
iX, iY =  convert_RT_to_XY(imm, jmm)   
iX = np.ndarray.flatten(iX)                                                                                    
iY = np.ndarray.flatten(iY)                                                                                    
iZ = np.ndarray.flatten(plot_function)                                                                         
f = interpolate.interp2d(iX, iY, iZ, kind='linear')
```

Ultimately, I want to perform:

```
result = dblquad(f, 10, 30,
    lambda x: 10,
    lambda x: 30))
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into SciPy's [`RectBivariateSpline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline).  If you are placing your data on a Cartesian grid anyway, it performs much faster than `interp2D`

Comment: I had a crash when I tried that after 55 minutes:

```RuntimeWarning:     A theoretically impossible results when finding a smoothin spline```

What is strange is that the data I have is relatively well behaved, all positive, real-valued and no poor features other than discontinuities due to it being on a grid.  However, when I try to use `interp2d` on data processed onto a _regular_ Cartesian grid, I get a result but it is completely _nan_.  Same deal for using `RectBivariateSpline`.